# Programmatic tab bar with tabviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a beginner in `Objective C` and I want to create a class for my tab bar controller to add item add items which are named from an API and these items are link to my `TableViewController` (here it's `ScheduleListViewController`).

I have done that but it doesn't work because I think (and it's sure) I'm doing it badly.

So to explain my goal, I have to create an item in my tab bar with its `ScheduleListViewController` (which is a `tableViewController`).

Here is my code :

```
#import "ChannelListTsbleBarVC.h"
#import "TVSHOW.h"
#import "ScheduleListTableViewController.h"
#import "TLAnimatedSegue.h"

@interface ChannelListTsbleBarVC ()

@end

@implementation ChannelListTsbleBarVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://apis.is/tv"];
  NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
  NSError* error;
  NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:JSONData //1
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
  NSArray* jsonResult = [json objectForKey:@"channels"];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

  for (id item in jsonResult) {
    ScheduleListTableViewController *Channel = [[ScheduleListTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *sett = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: Channel];
    [sett.tabBarItem setTitle:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];
    Channel = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];
  }
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you post the issue after putting a breakpoint at  [sett.tabBarItem setTitle:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];

Comment: @KumarUtsav No crash however the breakpoints is not reached

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code `for (id item in jsonResult)`

should be changed to 
    `for (NSDictionary *item in jsonResult)`